# Python, I tried to read data using stdin and covert to list, but it seems the data is lost outside for loop

Tags: python, list, stdin

I tested the following code with some data, the list works fine inside the for loop. But after the for loop, the list contains nothing. How come? I need the list for further use inside the program, so I can't manually interrupt it using keyboard.

```
l = []


for line in sys.stdin:
    if line == '':
        l.append([])
    else:
        new_list = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
        l.append(new_list)
        print(l)  # list works

print(l)  # list fails
```

Comment: Have you tried to use input() or in python2.x raw_input to get the input?

Comment: There is a *blackhole* between the `for` and the final `print`? Some code you're not showing?

Comment: Your code works for me (even though it never gets out of the loop, unless I press Ctrl + C and exit Python, at this moment I get an output of your list)

Comment: I tried input(), it doesn't work. I cannot figure out how to store data outside the for loop.

Comment: it [works for me](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#LcnLCsIwEIXhvU8xu0zqIHhBsNKtLxG6KNGBEXIhGTe@fEyLcBb/x2lcUgAui1dJsYKEnIoOu@eLgXFQO/rJPf73ak4FFCTCV/Lq@Z6LREWzN4d3kohhyVi1kLeWzGSofgL2bozuSHAiOG@7zgSu67apx2W27Qc).

Comment: Even in your code, you can add a simple         elif line.startswith('#'):
        break    and you can jump out using the character #

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are ever leaving the for loop to execute the second print(l) statement.

If you press ctrl-d for the end of file keyboard interupt, you will leave the for loop and the second print statement runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In order to go outside the for loop you have to break your code and there I guess the "l" information is lost!

You can use a character to move out of the loop (break) or use a while condition.
Ciao and have a nice day!

To get the input as suggested I would use the input or raw_input in python2!